# SASL authentication failure: client response doesn't match what we generated

Tags: postfix, authentication, sasl

The following tutorial has been used to setup a virtual mail server:

[How to set up a mail server on a GNU / Linux system](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/edition11.html)

Everything works fine, though every time a message is being sent the following errors appear:

```
mail postfix/smtpd[10569]: warning: SASL authentication failure: client response doesn't match what we generated (tried bogus)
mail postfix/smtpd[10569]: warning: unknown[so.me.ext.ip]: SASL DIGEST-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
mail postfix/smtpd[10569]: 1298562035: client=unknown[so.me.ext.ip], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=someuser@domain.com
```

and then it continues and sends the message.

According to this, etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
log_level: 7
allow_plaintext: true
auxprop_plugin: sql
sql_engine: mysql
sql_hostnames: 127.0.0.1
sql_user: mailuser
sql_passwd: mailpassword
sql_database: maildb
sql_select: select crypt from users where id='%u@%r' and enabled = 1
```

works fine except the digest-md5 part which then moves directly to login (and successfully sends the message).

Furthermore, /etc/default/saslauthd (omitted # text)

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="pam"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
#OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/run/saslauthd"
```

Works without a problem under the chroot environment of postfix or else the error would be

```
warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
```

It is an old setup that has worked like a charm for about four years already, still i want to make sure that those messages doesn't mean something has broken in between.

Answer (score 2):

Your question helped me dig... I've recently upgraded my mail server from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS and it's been a nightmare.  But finally everything is working :)

Your error:

```
SASL authentication failure: client response doesn't match what we generated (tried bogus)
```

was caused by my config in `/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf` containing:

```
mech_list: plain login cram-md5 digest-md5
```

The [Postfix SASL Howto](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) states that only plain & login are supported, and "authentication will fail if clients are allowed to choose other mechanisms", so the line should read:

```
mech_list: plain login
```

---

The last line:

```
warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
```

is caused by postfix now being run in a chroot, and `/var/run/saslauthd/` has moved to `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/`.

This is set at the end of `/etc/default/saslauthd`:

```
OPTIONS="-c -r -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Note that I added the -r flag to include the realm when authenticating (eg: it will authenticate using `aaron@example.com` instead of `aaron`).

---

Finally I also had to create `/etc/pam.d/smtp` with the following:

```
auth    required   pam_mysql.so user=mail passwd=******** host=******** db=maildb table=users usercolumn=id passwdcolumn=crypt crypt=1
account sufficient pam_mysql.so user=mail passwd=******** host=******** db=maildb table=users usercolumn=id passwdcolumn=crypt crypt=1
```

I'm sure you've long figured this by now, but I'm sharing anyway to save some other poor soul from gray hairs.  Postgreys... :/